# How to click on map and open page of state?

Tags: laravel, dictionary

I have a map like this.

[map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2RNR.png)

I want to open the province page when a user clicks on the province.

blade.php

```
<path onclick="parent.location.assign('http://localhost:8000/tourism/newyork')" class="NewYork" d=" M 322.03 227.95 C 319.84 226.68 321.35 222.19 323.96 223.37 C 330.39 224.41 336.80 225.64 343.16 227.04 C 348.44 228.07 352.49 231.90 357.48 233.68 C 359.80 234.56 362.17 235.33 364.52 236.14 C 364.83 237.64 365.15 239.15 365.47 240.67 C 360.74 242.31 355.77 243.14 351.10 244.90 C 346.81 246.02 347.83 251.28 346.16 254.43 C 343.86 256.42 340.68 257.36 338.89 259.94 C 337.06 262.50 335.71 265.36 334.23 268.13 C 334.13 265.83 334.02 263.53 333.92 261.24 C 332.28 261.00 330.64 260.76 329.01 260.53 C 328.87 263.09 328.72 265.66 328.57 268.23 C 327.94 266.28 327.30 264.32 326.70 262.37 C 321.87 262.27 317.03 262.45 312.20 262.11 C 312.10 259.41 311.57 256.67 312.03 253.98 C 314.93 250.92 319.36 250.12 322.83 247.88 C 327.95 244.74 330.84 238.90 331.54 233.06 C 328.32 231.46 324.89 230.16 322.03 227.95 Z" />
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/tourism/{tourismSlug}', [App\Http\Controllers\TourismController::class, 'single']);
```

TourismController.php

```
public function single(Tourism $tourism)
{
    $state = Tourism::query()->whereHas('state')->get();
    return $state   ;
}
```

Tourism.php

```
use HasFactory, Sluggable;

protected $guarded = [];

public function sluggable(): array
{
    return [
        'slug' => [
            'source' => 'city.name'
        ],
    ];
}

public function state()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(State::class);
}

public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(City::class);
}

public function path()
{
    $locale = app()->getLocale();
    return "/$locale/tourism/$this->slug";
}
```

When I click on any province: I see this message.

> 404 Not Found